# Use a dynamic file list to parallelize in Concourse

Tags: file, parallel-processing, directory, concourse, directory-listing

I'm sure this question is either extremely stupid or answered a million times but I can't find it here.

One thing I generally do with dynamic configuration settings in CI servers is generate separate parallel executions of tests by reading the list of test BDD files and generating a command to spawn a testing job for each. Am I correct in assuming that there is no way to do this in Concourse and I have to hard code the parallel execution into the configuration and maintain it separately?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried just running the parallel builds in single container?

Comment: I don't want to for various reasons, but sure yes that works fine.